# Were Isildur's traces of the ring in the right order?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring

Copied from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17459/120088), as I don't have an English copy of LotR:

> Already the writing upon it, which at first was as clear as red flame, fadeth and is now only barely to be read. It is fashioned in an elven-script of Eregion, for they have no letters in Mordor for such subtle work; but the language is unknown to me. I deem it to be a tongue of the Black Land, since it is foul and uncouth. What evil it saith I do not know; but I trace here a copy of it, lest it fade beyond recall.

As the ring was fashioned, at least in the films:

[image: Picture of the One Ring from the LotR films]

In the case where somebody does not understand what has been written, it would IMO be rather difficult to transcribe it in the correct order and not begin in the middle. So, did Isildur begin the trace at the start of the sentence or in the middle? If he started in the correct order, how did he do that, are there any indications on the ring on where the phrase begins and ends?

To address Paul D. Waite's comment, I link the image of the text I got from [lotr.fandom.com](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/One_Ring):

[image: Inscription on the ring]

On that image, which has no official value (AFAIK), there are two identical size gaps.

For reference, here is a phonetic transcription into Latin characters of the text pictured above:

> Ash nazg durbatulûk
>
> Ash nazg gimbatul
>
> Ash nazg thrakatulûk
>
> Agh burzum-ishi krimpatul

<sup>*The Lord of the Rings*, Book II, Chapter 2</sup>

Comment: I mean, there’s a big-ass gap right there in your picture. That’s probably the start and end.

Comment: Isildur did not understand the language, but it was written in an elven script, and may have followed similar rules to writing elven languages.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Maybe. Looking at this picture: https://static0.gamerantimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Lord-of-the-Rings-Amazon-Prime.jpg?q=50&fit=contain&w=960&h=500&dpr=1.5 there is another gap of similar size after the "k". I don't have an "official" 3D Modell of the ring on how Tolkien described the ring in details to check if it's the only such gap.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Added a specification according to your comment. Also, that would've been the wrong gap: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/2/23/One_Ring_inscription.svg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/454?cb=20080724233715

Comment: Does it matter? As soon as someone who knew the language read it, that would be able to figure out where the correct start and end were from context. Imagine: “them all and in the darkness bind them one ring to rule them all one ring to find them one ring to bring”. The rhyme doesn’t hurt either.

Comment: @ToddWilcox It doesn't matter in the great scheme of things for LotR, no. But I started wondering and this is for me the go-to site if I start wondering about something SciFi / Fantasy related.

Comment: @suchiuomizu Does Elvish orthography use capitalization, punctuation, position-dependent character systems that would provide cues to sentence structure? (I'm not an Elvish language geek, so I don't know the answers there. However, if the answers are all "No," then I think Shade's question is reasonable.)

Comment: @Lexible Looks like “no”. We can see the elvish script in question in the question. There are two dots but they are not periods, they are part of the characters that make up the word that is translated as “all”. That does highlight the rhyme in the text. If you look, the rhymes are visible between the top and bottom of the wheel of text and again between the left and right sides. You can also tell the beginning and end of the text if you know that the first three lines start with “one ring”, since the same characters begin three of the groups of characters.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "The tough coughs as he ploughs through the dough" would seem to invalidate your argument about rhymes necessarily resulting from repeated characters. Also the "if you know" argument is specious: Isildur **didn't know**.

Comment: @Lexible I wasn’t talking about Isildur. I guess I thought that went without saying. I was talking about whether there’s capitalization or punctuation in the elvish script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A drawing made by JRRT himself for the cover of *"The Fellowship of the Ring"* shows the ring inscription written on a circle, with:

- a **larger space** separating the end from the beginning
- **double circles** similar to ":" both at the beginning *and* at the end
- some **wavy lines** marking the beginning and the end of the ring verses.

With these features, it's impossible to copy the text starting at an incorrect position, even with no knowledge of the language or the characters.
Note that, while the larger space and the red lines could be considered not being a part of the inscription proper (just like the Three Rings or the eye of Sauron), the dots are clearly an element of the writing, as a *single* ":" separates the verses.

[image: cover drawing with the ring inscription]

The wavy lines are used in most editions of the book too, when the ring inscription is reported in the text (Book 1, Chapter 2, *"The Shadow of the Past"*), but they are before and after the first half of the inscription, maybe for simmetry.
In that case it would be possible to copy the ring inscription in a wrong way, with the second half before the first. Still, one could argue that the decorative characters denote a part with higher importance, so that section should be considered the first one.

[image: ring inscription in the book]

Comment: I don't have the volume of HOME covering the first part of _"The Lord of the Rings"_, so I cannot say whether it gives any info about how the ring inscription in Book 1, Chapter 2 came into its final form.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the physical presentation as noted in @Ifurini's answer...

Given that three of the clauses begin with the same sequence of letters, I think one could argue that Isildur simply recognized a common rhetorical device at work even in a language he did not understand. There are many examples in public speaking where the speaker uses an initial (or interior) motif three times in a row to set up, then changes it in the fourth clause.

One simple example in English:

```
You better watch out,
You better not cry
You better not pout
I’m telling you why
```

Or non-initially (with "I did not speak out"), Martin Niemöller's famous quotation:

```
First they came for the socialists, and I did not speak out—because I was not a socialist.
Then they came for the trade unionists, and I did not speak out—because I was not a trade unionist.
Then they came for the Jews, and I did not speak out—because I was not a Jew.
Then they came for me—and there was no one left to speak for me.
```

One could reasonably guess that the three clauses with the same initial letters and structure were the setup for the remaining clause.